# Scipy Global Optimization Algorithms: rescaling needed?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

Dear community members,

I am considering four global optimization algorithms offered in Scipy, namely, differential_evolution, dual_annealing, basinhopping and shgo to calibrate a model. My parameter space is 13 dimensional and parameter values lies in very different ranges as they represent different physical quantities ranging from 100s for one parameter to 1e-6 for another parameter. I was wondering if I need to scale all the parameters to the same scale (like linear scaling from 0 to 1)? As per my understanding, at least differential_evolution method is kind of affine-invariant so scaling is not required. Do other methods perform better if parameters are pre-scaled?  Do any of these methods scale parameters at their level? Any insights will be helpful.

Thanks